# Simplest way to parse a date time string like 20230202165638 in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, substring

I wonder is there any simpler way to parse a concatenated date time value like 20230202165638 in C# other than using substring function ?

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?

Comment: If you are on a current version of dotnet and find yourself using substring, I would just assume I am doing something wrong until proven otherwise.

Comment: @Fildor If Microsoft still keeps Substring function, maybe they are doing something wrong, you can stop them doing it.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't assume it's not needed for legacy reasons or even legit use cases any more. The number of which are just way smaller nowadays. To the point where I'd second guess myself when using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, there is an easier way, fully documented.

DateTime.ParseExact. Then define exactly how the string looks - the Formatstring specification is not that arcane and at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

It is a part you better learn where to find - if you ever deal with any input/output, that is amazingly good to do.

Another way - halfway between substring and parseexact - would be a regex, where any decent AI can help you write the string (as in: write the string for you).